# Append Collections.Liquid file through public app

Tags: shopify-app

I am a PHP Developer and, I am trying to append the theme functionality of any Shopify Theme, Though Public App. I did that by opening the theme file but now I want to implement that functionality through an app.

Comment: I want to know how to append Shopify theme functionality, Through App

Comment: Like "sv variations on collection page" app in shopify.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to change theme code via API like in [this page](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/online-store/asset)

First use `GET /admin/api/2019-07/themes.json` to see which theme shop is using. Check if `"role" : "main"` then take the theme id.

After get the id, you can send a json to `PUT /admin/api/2019-07/themes/{theme_id_from_step_one}/assets.json` to alter the file in the code without open it.

```
{
  "asset": {
    "key": "templates/index.liquid", // file location
    "value": "<img src='backsoon-postit.png'><p>We are busy updating the store for you and will be back within the hour.</p>" //delete liquid code inside and put those code in
  }
}
```

In case you only want to append the code. You must use GET /admin/themes/828155753/assets.json?asset[key]={file_location} . It gives

```
{
  "asset": {
    "key": "templates/index.liquid",
    "public_url": null,
    "value": "<!-- LIST 3 PER ROW -->\n<h2>Featured Products</h2>\n<table id=\"products\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">\n  {% tablerow product in collections.frontpage.products cols:3 %}\n    <a href=\"{{product.url}}\">{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'small' | img_tag }}</a>\n    <h3><a href=\"{{product.url}}\">{{product.title}}</a></h3>\n    <ul class=\"attributes\">\n      <li><span class=\"money\">{{product.price_min | money}}</span></li>\n    </ul>\n  {% endtablerow %}\n</table>\n<!-- /LIST 3 PER ROW -->\n\n{{ content_for_index }}\n\n<div id=\"articles\">\n  {% assign article = pages.frontpage %}\n  <div class=\"article\">\n    {% if article.content != \"\" %}\n      <h3>{{ article.title }}</h3>\n      <div class=\"article-body textile\">\n        {{ article.content }}\n      </div>\n    {% else %}\n      <div class=\"article-body textile\">\n        In <em>Admin &gt; Blogs &amp; Pages</em>, create a page with the handle <strong><code>frontpage</code></strong> and it will show up here.\n        <br />\n        {{ \"Learn more about handles\" | link_to \"http://wiki.shopify.com/Handle\" }}\n      </div>\n    {% endif %}\n  </div>\n</div>\n",
    "created_at": "2010-07-12T15:31:50-04:00",
    "updated_at": "2010-07-12T15:31:50-04:00",
    "content_type": "text/x-liquid",
    "size": 1068,
    "theme_id": 828155753
  }
}
```

take the value and use regex to append.